# How can I add a close button to pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, button, popup

I am in way over my head, new to S/O and need to get this done as soon as possible. If I am doing this wrong I apologize in advance.

I purchased an extension that was simple enough to install but I need to extend the function just a but. I reached out to the developer to no avail.

Anyway I need to add a close button to the pop ups featured on the home page of this website (http://www.juanlafontalaw.com) Click on one of the hotspots (Red) and the pop up will appear. I simply need to add a close button or X that will allow the user to close the pop up without touching the main screen.

The site is Wordpress based. Plug-in: Visual Composer. The Extension: Visual Composer Add-on Image Hotspot with Tooltip (This is the focal point of my question)

I have no idea where to begin and did not expect to be in this position. And I did not think the develop -who does offer support to totally ignore my

Comment: The link doesn't work. Questions on SO should not depend on external websites to be used for this exact reason: links can die. Code that needs improving should be posted in the question - I think you're out of luck for the kind of issue you have.

Comment: Thanks Jacque. I put the wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

Make a button in html, and use jquery click function to make display none in the pop up

```
$("#btn-id").click(function(){
 $("pop-up").css("display","none");
})
```

Comment: Thank you Johnny. I understand how to make a button using HTML  but unsure how to add the jquery to it. Also, I think the wordpress editor will strip most of the code. Any additional insight is greatly appreciated.